# can I pass multiple path location webpack exclude module path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

My files are :- "/node_modules/"  and "/app/styles/old_css/".

Actuality I am expecting like this

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: "style-loader",
        use: ['css-loader?importLoaders=1', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']

    }),
    exclude: ['/node_modules/', '/app/styles/old_css/']
 }
```

Comment: `exclude` takes a [`Condition`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition) and a `Condition` can be an array of other `Condition`s.

Comment: hey, @Tholle I am unable to solve my problem. could you please guide me for "how to avoid my old CSS file's folder and node_modules too in webpack build.